# jquery dialog gives missing : after property id error

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to popup the jquery dialogue box here. 
when I dialog
 has the following code..

```
var opt = {
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 550,
        height:650,
        title: 'Details'
};
```

It works fine. I get the popup window. But adding additional info is getting me this error.

**Updated Post**

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".editbt").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: this.href,
        cache:false,
        success: function(response){
        var opt = {
         box :$( "#box" ),
      itemname:$( "#itemname" ),
      size:$( "#size" ),
      potency:$( "#potency" ),
      quantity:$( "#quantity" ),

      allFields:$( [] ).add( box ).add(itemname).add(size).add(potency).add(quantity),
      tips :$( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }


  function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Please enter the field " );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 600,
      width: 500,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "edit": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
 bValid = bValid && checkLength( box, "box", 1, 16 );
  bValid = bValid && checkLength( itemname, "itemname", 1, 16 );         
  bValid = bValid && checkLength( size, "size", 1, 16 );       
 bValid = bValid && checkLength( potency, "potency", 1, 16 ); 
   bValid = bValid && checkLength( quantity, "quantity", 1, 16 );        

          if ( bValid ) {
            $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
              "<td>" + box.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + itemname.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + size.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + potency.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + quantity.val() + "</td>" +
            "</tr>" );
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });
};

            if (response.length > 0) {  
            var wrapperelement = document.getElementById('display');

                wrapperelement.innerHTML = response; 
                $("#dialog-form").dialog(opt).dialog("open");

            }
        }
 });

});



 });

</script>
```

Any idea?? Thank you for your time..

Comment: Why are you using `=` instead of `:`? Have you even bothered to check the console for errors? the errors are self explanatory.

Comment: @Zenith Yes I did check.. It showed the error..I didn't know this was object creation..I am doing it for the first time..

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude by the way, it's just that by pasting your code into JSbin or checking in your console, you will see each error and what is causing it very quickly. You should always do that before posting

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. You are creating a javascript object, the syntax for which is:

```
var opt = {
    box: $( "#box" ),
    itemname: $( "#itemname" ),
    size: $( "#size" ),
    potency: $( "#potency" ),
    quantity: $( "#quantity" ),
    .
    .
}
```

Also, the `var` ahead of `box` is not needed.

You can also do it as:

```
var opt = new Object();
opt.box = $( "#box" );
opt.itemname: $( "#itemname" );
.
.
```

Comment: if you mean like this - `var opt = { xyz: function() }`, then yes, you  can.